# Show that $|\frac{z-a}{\bar az-zz}|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that $|\frac{z-a}{\bar az-zz}|=1$, if $a$ and $z$ are any complex numbers, where $z$ does not equal $a$ and $|z|=1$

I tried to use the property that $\bar zz = |z|^2=1$ and factorising out a $|z|$ from the denominator but I'm not sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let $z=i$ and $a=-i$.

Comment: Does not look very true when $z=\bar a$ ?

Comment: $\Big|\dfrac{z-a}{\overline{az}-zz}\Big|=1$ is better!

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked a few times.

Comment: Here's a list of similar questions which I'm sure are useful: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666400/prove-that-left-fracz-w1-bar-w-z-right-1-if-z-1-and-w-neq-1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497917/showing-that-left-fracz-a1-baraz-right-1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666214/proving-left-fracw-z1-barwz-right-1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343982/prove-if-z-1-and-w-1-then-1-zw-neq-0-and-z-w-over-1).